# selenium code for accessing button type submit in c#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the text in an input box,

```
<input value="Add a Phone" onclick="CSS.addClass($(&quot;u_0_4&quot;), &quot;async_saving&quot;); new AsyncRequest().setURI(&quot;\/ajax\/phone\/confirmation&quot;).setData({source: &quot;www_mobile_settings&quot;}).setStatusElement($(&quot;u_0_4&quot;)).send();" type="submit" id="u_0_5">
```

I have tried for ;

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_5")).Click()
```

but raising an error of : No such element Unable to locate Element

Comment: your web element is incorrect (ID)

Comment: you can help me goto your facebook account and setting and mobile
see photo https://prnt.sc/ul3fjl
i want click to add a phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `Add a Phone` is present inside an `iframe`.You need to `switch` the `iframe` first in order to access the element.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[src^='https://www.facebook.com/settings?']")));
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value='Add a Phone']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that button, you can use CSS selector here is one

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='submit'][value='Add a Phone']")).Click()
```

or by XPATH

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@value,'Add a Phone')]")).Click()
```

Comment: no such element
 you can help me goto your facebook account and setting and mobile see photo https://prnt.sc/ul3fjl i want click to add a phone

Comment: are you sure you are waiting for the element to be displayed?

Comment: I'm using the same code and it works - also try by xpath driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@value,'Add a Phone')]")).Click()

Comment: use chromedrive or firefoxdrive ?

Comment: it doesn't matter the browser, the element is there and it's clickable - did u tried xpath? I updated the answer with the code

Comment: update you post with your code to see what are you doing